# Why some userprofiles are showing domain\username and others showing firstname, lastname?

Tags: user-profile

I am using sp 2010. I see some users are showing "domain\username" and others as "firstname, lastname". I can fix this to run this powershell comando:

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'domain\username' -Web http://portal.myCompany.com -SyncFromAD
```

I have found also a script how I can find these corrupted userprofiles in a website:

```
Get-SPUser -Limit All –Web  http://portal.myCompany.com | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName –like "myDomain*"}
```

Why do I need always fix this? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

im just guessing here.....

the domain users are comming from active directory and the other users that only show first and last are created localy or directly on sharepoint ;)

creating a sharepoint account that is local to sharepoint only:

> Add a user account 
>   1.On the Site Administration page, under Users and roles, click Manage users.
>
> 2.Click Add a user.
>
> 3.In the User area, click Add a new user with the following information, and then type the username and password for the new user
>   account.
>
> 4.In the User Role area, select a user role for the new account.
>
> 5.Click Add User.

create an account from an existing account found on active directory that would contain the domain name:

> Add an account from an existing network group or domain  Use this
>   method to either add an existing user with a domain account to a web
>   or subweb, or to add an existing user with a local machine account to
>   a subweb.
>
> 1.On the Site Administration page, under Users and roles, click Manage users.
>
> 2.In the User area, click Add user or group name, and then type the account's group or domain name and username, for example
>   mydomain\username1 .
>
> 3.In the User Role area, select a user role for the new account.
>
> 4.Click Add User.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768246.aspx

Comment: the target is to get all users from AD. We have an AD connection which gets alot of users. How can I test if a user (which shows domain\username) is synced by the AD connection?